# Как сделать блоки,как в фигме

Tags: html, css

Нужно сделать блоки,как в фигме

[image: блоки]

блоки со стрелками,как их сделать,как в фигме???У них углы закруглённые

вот фигма : [https://www.figma.com/file/8PAR14gUclVbOKYFgu962x/страничка-(Copy)?node-id=371%3A2040](https://www.figma.com/file/8PAR14gUclVbOKYFgu962x/%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-(Copy)?node-id=371%3A2040)

Answer (score 1):

Вообщем,тут ответа так и не дождался(

Справился сам,с помощью css-clip.

https://www.cssportal.com/css-clip-path-generator/ - вот ссылка на ресурс,где можно всё это реализовать,он вам выдаст css код на clip

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)